# listen to a plotting event in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, events, plot, listener

I need to follow after specific axes to know when plotting been performed there.

That to be able to adjust some other gui elements to the newly plotted data.

As a minimal tasks, for example, I would like to track changes in XLim. However listener to XLim property is not triggered if a new plot is responsible for it.

Example below produces output:

```
Event: XLim = [1 2]
And now (without event triggered) XLim = [1 5]
```

Example:

```
clear all
close all
clear handles
plot(1:10)
ax = gca;
addlistener(ax, 'XLim', 'PostSet', @(x,y) fprintf('Event: XLim = [%d %d]\n',y.AffectedObject.XLim));
ax.XLim = [1 2];
plot(1:5)
fprintf('And now (without event triggered) XLim = [%d %d]\n',ax.XLim)
```

It seems to be not MATLABian way to build gui, which assumes explicit axes formatting commands to FOLLOW plotting commands.

Will be grateful for some smart work-around ideas.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. Please explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.

Comment: Is it your own application that does the plotting on those axes? Can't you explicitly adjust the GUI elements after the plot?

Comment: @Adriaan - I do not have a code to show - the question is about MATLAB capabilities and how to use them to achieve my goals.

Comment: @LuisMendo I would like to prepare axis for others to plot on them. That's why solution with applying explicit formatting after the plotting is not desirable - and some sort of listener could possibly do that.

Comment: @ipap I see. To make sure I understood the question: you tried `addlistener` and it didn't work, right? For me that works for example when I modify the axis limits with `xlim`, but not when a `plot` modifies the axis limits. The strange thing is that according to [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/property-value-change-listeners) (which is very good blog) it should: "his will trigger myCallbackFcn(hAxes,eventData) whenever the axes limits change (_due to zoom, pan, plotting etc_.):"

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, you are right. Explicit change of XLim in code or by panning/zoomin triggers the listenere - but the plotting command  does not.